# Difference between logging exception and exception.printstacktrace

Tags: java, exception, logging

Could you please clarify me the difference when I just used a logger with

```
 LOGGER.error("Exception is -- " , exception);
```

and

```
 LOGGER.error("Exception is -- " , exception.printStackTrace());
```

Which one is better to get more details about exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that the second one doesn't compile. `printStackTrace()` is a `void` method.

Normally, when people involve `printStackTrace()`, they write

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

instead of

```
LOGGER.error(message, e);
```

but don't combine these two in one line.

Anyway, never use `.printStackTrace()` in an application which already has logging because your stack trace may not even make it to the logs, and it will appear in the `System.err` stream, where nothing should be written from an app which has proper logging.

Answer (score 3):

```
LOGGER.error("Exception is -- " , exception.printStackTrace());
```

Its invalid statement. [`Throwable#printStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) method's return type is **void** and it prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream.

You may find the difference between `LOGGER.error("Exception is -- " , exception);` and `exception.printStackTrace()`

Logging the exception with logger api(Ex. LOG4j, Logback etc) is write way to log or more convenient way as you can pre-define all log related setting. Like -

- Number Appenders to be defined
- Log print format
- Different file for different LOG.LEVEL

etc...